# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target Error during http Post request

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an Ionic 2 Project using Angular. The code returns an error at the line 5. Can someone please tell me what to do?

```
@Injectable()
export class DiaryService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {}  
    getData(): Promise<DiaryModel> {
      return this.http.post('./assets/example_data/diary.json')
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json() as DiaryModel)
       .catch(this.handleError);
    }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post` method takes at least 2 parameters - the *url* and the *body*.

You have passed only the *url* part. You need also to set the *body*.

```
return this.http.post('./assets/example_data/diary.json', body)
```

Also `Http` is deprecated, try the newer [**HttpClient**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data/body` parameter,

```
 return this.http.post('./assets/example_data/diary.json',data)
```

Comment: oh, my bad! Thanks a lot!